# Generate a GoogleMap snapshot from a not visible fragment

Tags: android, maps, snapshot

What I'm trying to obtain is a map snapshot but from a layout not visible to the user, so that I can show the user only the snapshot but not the actual creating process. If I try to take it from a layout with visibility set to invisible I get this error:

```
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:695)**
```

Layout xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map_holder"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:visibility="invisible">

    <fragment
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        map:uiRotateGestures="false"
        class="com.vodafone.glympseplugin.maps.Map" />
```

And this is the code in the onCreate():

```
    Bitmap mapBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(200,200,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    SupportMapFragment mapfragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    GoogleMap map = mapfragment.getMap();

    map.snapshot(this, mapBitmap);
```

Obviousely the problem is that the map fragment is not yet inflated and measured. How can I solve the issue, creating a bitmap from a not visible map?

I tried also to call the layout(...) and measure(...) on the parent ViewGroup of the fragment but the result is the same.

Comment: Try to add the fragment to the main layout of your activity/screen but somewhere it's not visible. For example move it outside of the screen via margins.

Comment: Thx @damian Actually this seems to work. But I'm trying to understand if is there another way to do it without bringing up a "fake" activity but programmatically from a real one. What I mean is that seems an hack more than a solution.